# Selenium install geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to use selenium webdriver firefox but get this error when executing `webdriver.Firefox()`:

```
log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

I downloaded geckdriver for windows 64 bit ( i heard doesn't really matter if 32 or 64 for windows) extracted it to:

```
C:Users\my_name\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone2\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox
```

right clicked This PC, the Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environmental Variables->System variables->Path->Edit->New

Here I pasted the path:

```
C:Users\my_name\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone2\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\geckodriver.exe
```

Then ran `webdriver.Firefox()`

and yet got the same error. I am running the latest version of firefox and using selenium 3.141

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: not related to this but alternative of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727916/6660373 use `webdriver-manager` instead you won't be facing path issues then

Comment: @Pygirl thanks but I can't do pip installs on my work station. Python is installed with arcgis pro and you can only install packages in cloned environments and I need to run python from the read only env in cmd line to perform pip installs but I can't actualy install anything because it is read only.